Typescript create a list of objects inside a list of objects
I'm a sort of a begginer in typescript
My idea is to have a list of projects and each project would have a tasks list with each task having a status that would indicate their completion level, which are:
A - to do
B - doing
C - done
My attempt
I tried doing something using what I believed to be the right logic, but it doesn't really work

projectslist: {
    name: string,
    tasks: [{
      taskName: string,
      taskStatus: string
    }]
  }[] = [
      {
        name: 'project A',
        tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' },
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' },
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' },
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project B', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' },
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' },
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project C', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project D', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project E', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project F', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' }
        { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project G', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'C' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'project H', tasks: [
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'B' }
          { taskName: 'randomTask', taskStatus: 'A' }
        ]
      },
    ];


What I was expecting
I was expecting to be able to create data manually so I could test the frontend, but I can't seem to figure out the logic on creating a list inside a list
What I got
It says there's two errors
error 1
    Type '[{ taskName: string; taskStatus: string; }, { taskName: string; taskStatus: string; }, { taskName: string; taskStatus: string; }, { taskName: string; taskStatus: string; }]' is not assignable to type '[{ taskName: string; taskStatus: string; }]'.
  Source has 4 element(s) but target allows only 1.

error 2
   The expected type comes from property 'tasks' which is declared here on type '{ name: string; tasks: [{ taskName: string; taskStatus: string; }]; }'


• Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have plenty of syntax errors here, lots of missing commas. Please [edit] fix them so that the errors we get are only the errors you're asking about. • The type [X] is a one-element tuple; if you want an array of an arbitrary number of elements, you want the type X[] instead. Change your tasks type from [⋯] to ⋯[] and everything works.
